# Change the background of selected LI using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, menu, html-lists, master-pages

I want to change the background color of LI Tag that I have clicked....
But the problem is , that the code(both JQuery and LI list) is on masterpage(Admin.master) , 
I have written the following code on **Admin.Master** page...But it doesnt seem to Work.....

```
    <div id="main_menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="dashboard.aspx">Dashboard</a> </li>
                <li><a href="Contacts.aspx">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="MeetingA.aspx">Schedule Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="Tasks.aspx">Task</a></li>
                <li><a href="Calendar.aspx">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="Documents.aspx">Documents</a></li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**My JQuery Code is:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("li").click(function(){
               $('li').removeClass('selected');
               $(this).addClass('selected');
              });
            });
```

Style :

```
  <style type="text/css">
    li { color: #000; } li.selected { color: #FF0000; } 
  </style>
```

All the code is on MasterPage, but not getting the solution..

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: - My JQuery Code is:
    $(document).ready(function(){            
                    $("li").click(function(){$('li').removeClass('selected');                         $(this).addClass('selected');                       
                    });
        });

 - Style  :
        <style type="text/css">
li { color: #000; }
li.selected { color: #FF0000; }
</style>

Comment: Edit your question and put code there. Why does it matter where html and jQ are?

Comment: Well I am not sure, why it isnt working.....on masterpage !!!

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to change the background color of `<li>` Tag that I have clicked...*

But you're trying to change the font `color`, not the `background-color`. So my guess is that `<a>` has already a color defined that overrides that of `<li>`.
Try with `background-color` and check that `<a>` is not overriding that style.

```
li.selected { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

**EDIT:** Like **sngregory** said, you'll probably want to intercept and cancel the default behavior of `<a>`. So you can rewrite your code like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: You also need to account for the fact that the li tags you're click on contain hyperlinks. Clicking on them will reload the page, unless you intercept the click in some other code...

Comment: ohh.. sorry I actually  added the wrong style here... in my style, i have used li.selected { background-color: #FF0000; }

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

I've created quick [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FJCCW/).

With some conditional statements you can do some creative stuff from this point on.
Hope that helps.